# DB Connection pooling for oracle using JOOQ

Tags: oracle11g, database-connection, java-7, connection-pooling, jooq

We are currently using JOOQ in our project to interact with Orcale DB. Now there is a requirement where we need to create a process monitoring app which will monitor a set of backend processes. We build a java app which spwan threads for each processes and monitor its status and also logs into a table if anything goes wrong.

But the above process is failing with multiple thread environment. i.e if we try to start all the processes at the same time it throws an error showing protocol violation. We are suspecting it may be due the fact that we are using single database connection(singleton scope) for all the processes.

Can anyone help us in implementing connection pool supported by JOOQ which may resolve the issue? Any other suggestions are also welcomed.

Thanks,
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

You will find an example of how to use jOOQ with Spring and Apache DBCP on the jOOQ website here:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-with-spring

Essentially, you have to provide jOOQ with a pooled `DataSource` through [`DSL.using(DataSource, SQLDialect)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#using-javax.sql.DataSource-org.jooq.SQLDialect-), or by implementing your own [`ConnectionProvider`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html).

Note there was also a bug, which was fixed in jOOQ 3.2.2, which caused similar issues liek the ones you're experiencing:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2863